# Order of Plotly Text Annotation in imshow

Tags: plotly

I am not able to understand the order of text annotation as they appear in an array of images. I have a numpy array of 10x28x28 with each subarray having values 0.1,0.2 all the way to 0.9

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output,callback
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

X = np.zeros((10,28,28))
y = np.zeros(10,)

for i in range(10):

   X[i,::,::] = i/10
   y[i] = i


fig = px.imshow(X[:, :, :], binary_string=False, zmin=0, zmax=1,
            facet_col=0, aspect = 'auto', facet_col_wrap=5,
            facet_row_spacing = 0, color_continuous_scale='rdylgn')

for n,i in enumerate(fig.layout.annotations):
   i['text']=str(n)

fig.show()
```

With the chosen color scheme, the 0th image should appear red and the 9th as green. All well so far. However , when I update the annotations with the array index , their order is completely haywire. The top-left image is the 0th subarray , hence it should have a text annotation of 0. Similarly , the bottom-right is the last subarray and it should have an annotation 9.
Please help me understand the order in which the text annotation can be controlled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, this phenomenon occurs because the order of annotations and graphs are different. It is easiest to use the subtitles, which are created by default, for the annotations.

```
fig = px.imshow(X[:, :, :], binary_string=False, zmin=0, zmax=1,
            facet_col=0, aspect = 'auto', facet_col_wrap=5,
            facet_row_spacing = 0, color_continuous_scale='rdylgn')

for n,i in enumerate(fig.layout.annotations):
   i['text']=i.text.split('=')[1]

fig.show()
```

[image]